# How to access value in an Ordered Dictionary when even one of the keys is an integer?

Tags: c#, dictionary, key-value, ordereddictionary

I have an OrderedDictionary as shown in the below code snippet where keys are strings, integer and character .

Well I am quite new  to OrderedDictionary and all I know is that an ordered dictionary can store any type of key/value pairs and we can access values through both index and keys.

```
        OrderedDictionary od = new OrderedDictionary();

        od.Add("Key1", "Val1");
        od.Add("Key2", "Val2");
        od.Add("Key3", "Val3");
        od.Add(1, "Val4");
        od.Add('k', 'V');
```

So, I was wondering if I need to access Val4 above, then how should I do it? Because when I am trying to use

```
        Console.WriteLine(od[1]);
```

it is giving me 'Val2' as it is clearly considering '1' as an index.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can cast the integer value of 1 to object to hit the correct indexer.

```
Console.WriteLine(od[(object)1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Cast the argument to an object to force the use of the object indexer:

```
  Console.WriteLine(od[(object)1]);
```

That should work.